# export native excel date as text string

Tags: excel, vba, date, csv

Today I have a problem of trying to write a csv file line by line with one of the columns formatted as a native excel date.  My script works but doesn't export the date correctly and is being exported as as serial string.  I simply want the exported file to write the date in the "mm/dd/yyyy" format.  Any ideas?

```
Sub OUTPUT_COMMA_DELIMITED_RANGE()

Dim outputPath As String
Dim outputFileName As String
Dim rSrc As Range
Dim rSrcRow As Range
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim fOut As TextStream

On Error GoTo SomethingBadHappened
Dim MyPathFull As String



outputPath = "C:\workspace\Appendix_Working_Area\Script_Out\"

    outputFileName = "Z225R" & Chr(95) & "Eddy_Fluctuating_Zone.csv"
MyPathFull = outputPath & outputFileName


    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fOut = fso.CreateTextFile(outputPath & outputFileName)

    Dim EddyHghEleZoneRng As Range

    Set EddyHghEleZoneRng = Worksheets("225R").Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(1, 9).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
    Set rSrc = EddyHghEleZoneRng

    For Each rSrcRow In rSrc.Rows
        fOut.WriteLine Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose _
                           (Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rSrcRow)), ",")
    Next rSrcRow

    MsgBox "File " & outputPath & outputFileName & " created successfully"

SomethingBadHappened:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
On Error Resume Next
fOut.Close
If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 91 Then MsgBox "Unable to close file (" & Err.Description & ")"
End Sub
```

I have chosen to manually create the csv file because id don't want any of the unwanted characters associated with using the `FileFormat:=xlCSV` feature built in to excel.

To provide a sample of the kind of data i am dealing i have created an example of what i want the output csv file too look like.

Site,Date,Plane_Height,Area_2D,Area_3D,Volume,Errors
225r,11/3/1990,8kto25k,2212.834,2235.460,841.76655,88.513

Thanks,

dubbbdan

Comment: On Windows you can't use `/` in a file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your data is contained in 6 columns.  Here is a way to make a **.csv** which preserves date formats:

```
Sub MakeCSVFile()
    Dim N As Long, M As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim OutRec As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    M = 6
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\x.csv" For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To N
        OutRec = Cells(i, 1).Text
        For j = 2 To M
            OutRec = OutRec & "," & Cells(i, j).Text
        Next j
        Print #1, OutRec
    Next i
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: You are correct with assuming the 6 columns.  How would i make this script work if i have a range of data? I need to export mutiple csv's from each worksheet.

Comment: The code would need to know how many rows are associated with each **.csv**

Comment: That would go in the `N=` line?

Comment: **YES**   something similar to *For i = 345 to 678* .......must also change the *Open* line for each **.csv**

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to figure it out provided your example.  I changed the `N=` line to `N = EddyHghEleZoneRng.Rows.Count` and the `M=` line to `M = EddyHghEleZoneRng.Column + 6`.  cheers

Comment: One more quick question,  what is the first `close #1` for?  its on line 6 or your code.

Comment: It is a purely protective measure.........just in case a file was accidentally left open by a previous program.

Comment: I found one more caveat when using the above code to export dates in CSV's as text strings.  IF the date does not fit in the cell and is just displaying '######' instead of the date the script will export '######' instead of the date string.  Make sure the date fits and its displayed on the worksheet properly, and the code works  great.